# Repeated Background Query while app is running

Tags: android, mysql, service, handler

I find stackoverflow incredibly useful, but this time I cannot find an exact answer: I am afraid to pick up the wrong solution for my case.

I am creating an app that manage restaurant reservations.

When logged as a restaurant I'd like to have the possibility to call in the backgroud a query (that for sure I already have) periodically, that returns the number of new Reservation Inserts in the mysql db and update the notifications in my action bar (that I already have implemented).

I was going for Handler, or IntentService, or Service, but each time I've found some pro and cons and I really am stucked.

I would like to have this query running each 1-2-3 minutes (no important) only when the app is running, and the simple result of this query (just the number of new reservations) as an output to handle, in order to show it in my action bar.

Thanks to everybody

Matteo

Comment: What pros and cons did you find?

Comment: for example risk of high amount of resources drain using Services, or the fact that it would run even after the app has been exited.
I just wonder what could be the best solution for my case, that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform the query only when the app is in the foreground, then a [***bound*** `Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) may be just what you're looking for. Use `AsyncTask`s from within the `Service` to query the DB, and update the foreground `Activity` from the `Service`.

**EDIT:**

Answering point-wise:

**1.** To create a periodic `Service`, use `AlarmManager` and `PendingIntent`. There are any number of examples on the net for this.

**2.** A *bound* `Service` is active as long as the `Activity` is alive, and never otherwise. It can be stopped after it finishes its work. See the link above for more.

**3.** See the link above, and study a couple of examples, it will become clear.

Comment: //edited below ;)
I'll try right now. Just other hints: 
1) what's the best way to delay the service and make it run every T seconds?
2) is it my duty to stop the service before quitting my app?

//edited below ;)

3) how can I update the foreground Activity from within the Service? I don't think I can access the Activity context (yes ma'am, I am so noob in android, be merciful)

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Bies: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: Oh, I concentrated on other matters while waiting for your kind response and then I had lunch :)
I will start creating this Service very soon, though, in a copule of hours.
May I feel free to contact you if I should encounter any particoular issues?